# How to curl Google Authentication on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried to curl `Google Login` but error occurs so I couldn't.
My purpose is to be sure whether I realize jwt authentication in my Rails api project or not.

```
curl \
–request POST \
–data "code=https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?client_id=481457776943-bp1kqddm4hcd7u06hhtia17qbqutkf7f.apps.googleusercontent.com&as=RZYXbQ0V3RAbZXj1ikLhAg&destination=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000&approval_state=!ChRzbmFEa3ctS1FGUG9mSG9KRFdlNhIfc3dRTHJWQTMyaGNUNEJxcmlYbTVkb2xTUGdUdFloWQ%E2%88%99ANKMe1QAAAAAW7MwzDVl8UHd4sBHInNvsVqJls_goVMI&oauthgdpr=1&xsrfsig=AHgIfE9Dey82S4sRePRkB1Pf39CeuTFM-w&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

I inupt google login redirect url in `code`.

Comment: You can use rest-client and pass params which are required with post url, please have a look at answer given below

Answer (score 0):

I did that.

```
curl -d client_id=`Client ID` -d client_secret=`Client Secret` -d redirect_uri=`Redirect_uri` -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code=`Authentication Code` https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```